# Método alternativo ao view.Menu*

Tags: android, android-studio

Sou iniciante com programação Android e estou seguindo o livro "*Google Android*" (2012), da *Casa do Código*.

Cheguei em uma parte em que se deve criar "menus" usando as funções presentes em **android.view.Menu***, e o resultado esperado deveria ser algo como o da imagem abaixo:

[image: Exemplo do Livro]
Entretanto, ao executar em meu aparelho (Android 5.1.1) o menu não aparece e nenhum erro é disparado.

Fiz algumas pesquisas e cheguei a conclusão que isso ocorre por causa das versões mais novas do android não terem mais o botão de "opções" (ou algo assim).

Bom, eu gostaria de saber se existem formas alternativas de representar estes menus, uma vez que no decorrer do curso, novas implementações serão feitas usando estes menus.

Obrigado por sua atenção!

Michael.

Comment: posta o codigo do que voce já tem feito ai pra ter uma ideia do que que voce precisa

Comment: Provavelmente se você segurar(der um click longo) no botão minimizar da sua barra de navegação, irá aparecer o menu.

Comment: @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho - É um código bem simples, mas não vou esquentar a cabeça com isso. Como é apenas pra aprendizado, vou substituir o view.Menu por um AlertDialog (famosa gambiarra).

AckLay - Tentei, mas não funciona.

Obrigado!

Comment: O Android está em contaste mudança, se está a começar, não estude por material antigo.

Comment: @ramaral Eu comprei o livro da casa do código achando que ela era atualizada, mas parece que me enganei. De todo modo, ela é suficiente pra me dar uma base, nada que outras pesquisas não resolvam pra me aprimorar. Pode me recomendar algo?

Comment: Não. Normalmente recorro à Internet. Tenho sempre é atenção à data da publicação e vejo mais do que uma sobre o mesmo assunto. Não sei se é o seu caso mas antes do Android vem o Java, é necessário dominá-lo minimamente para tornar o aprendizado do Android mais fácil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa feature realmente mudou e hoje o Android não se comporta desse jeito. Isso pode ser verificado aqui:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

> O menu de opções é onde você deve incluir ações e outras opções que
>   são relevantes para o contexto de atividade atual, como "Buscar",
>   "Escrever e-mail" e "Configurações".
>
> O local onde os itens no menu de opções aparecem na tela depende da
>   versão em que o aplicativo foi desenvolvido:
>
> Caso tenha desenvolvido o aplicativo para Android 2.3.x (API de nível
>   10) ou inferior, os conteúdos do menu de opções aparecerão na parte
>   inferior da tela, quando o usuário pressionar o botão Menu, como
>   mostrado na figura 1. Quando aberto, a primeira parte visível é o menu
>   de ícones, que tem até seis itens de menu. Se o menu incluir mais de
>   seis itens, o Android colocará o sexto item e o restante em um menu
>   flutuante que o usuário poderá abrir selecionando Mais. Se você
>   desenvolveu o aplicativo para Android 3.0 (API de nível 11) ou
>   superior, os itens do menu de opções estão disponíveis na barra de
>   aplicativos. Por padrão, o sistema posiciona todos os itens nas ações
>   adicionais, que o usuário pode revelar com o ícone de ações adicionais
>   no lado direito da barra de aplicativos (ou pressionando o botão Menu
>   no dispositivo, se disponível). Para ativar o acesso rápido a ações
>   importantes, é possível promover alguns itens para aparecerem na barra
>   de aplicativos adicionando android:showAsAction="ifRoom" aos elementos
>    correspondentes (veja a figura 2). Para obter mais informações
>   sobre os itens de ação e outros comportamentos da barra de
>   aplicativos, consulte a aula Adição da barra do aplicativo.

Outro ponto a se considerar é que apenas 1.7% dos smartphones hojem utilizam  versão 2.3 do Android (Gingerbread), ou seja seria mais aconselhável você atualizar o seu material de estudo, posso sugerir até o site de developer do Android ou outras opções

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outros links para materiais mais atuais de Android:

- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Android/article.html
- https://developer.android.com/index.html
- http://www.nglauber.com.br/

Comment: @diegofm O gráfico foi retirado do site do proprio Android (https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html). Foi medido em 2016, porém acho que o meu ponto ainda continua válido.

Comment: De fato, não foi levantado ainda o marketshare do nougat, erro meu então.

Comment: Certo, então era o que eu imaginava mesmo...
Obrigado pelos links, serão de muita ajuda!

Comment: @RafaelLucena ainda tenho que me acostumar com esse modelo de postagem. Já sinalizei conforme pediu. Obrigado!